# Give me the users by searching and filtering for 4º octect ip address

Tags: r

An ip address consists of four decimal numbers, each ranging from 0 to 255, separated by dots.
I need to find a script in R that search for users which the last octect ip address is greater than or equal to 128.
Let's say I have the following data:

```
library(iptools)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

IP_LIST <- data.frame(
  "User" = c("John", "Carl", "Mary", 
             "Kim", "Jane", "Jessie",
             "Peter"),
  "IP" = c('172.16.0.15',
  '192.168.200.90',
  '172.16.2.129',
  '198.16.15.254',
  '172.25.25.19',
  '192.168.25.200',
  '192.129.200.10') )
```

The result should give me the users/ips:

```
User   IP_Address
Carl   172.16.2.129
Mary   192.16.15.254
Jessie 192.168.25.200
```

Because all those ip's last octects are greater than or equal to 128 (129, 254 and 200).

Answer (score 1):

Using base R we can extract everything after last dot, convert to integer, compare and subset

```
IP_LIST[as.integer(sub(".*\\.(\\d+)", "\\1", IP_LIST$IP)) > 128, ]

#    User             IP
#3   Mary   172.16.2.129
#4    Kim  198.16.15.254
#6 Jessie 192.168.25.200
```

---

Using the same logic we could have few more options using different libraries.

`stringi::stri_extract_last_regex` extracts last pattern. We could extract the last number using it and then follow the same process.

```
library(stringi)
IP_LIST[as.integer(stri_extract_last_regex(IP_LIST$IP, "\\d+")) > 128, ]
```

Without getting involved into regex we could use `word` function from `stringr` to get the last word with `sep`arator as dot (`.`)

```
library(stringr)
IP_LIST[as.integer(word(IP_LIST$IP, -1, sep = "\\.")) > 128, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

another `tidyverse` approach

```
library( tidyverse )
IP_LIST %>% filter( str_extract( IP, "[0-9]+$" ) %>% as.numeric() >= 128 )

#     User             IP
# 1   Mary   172.16.2.129
# 2    Kim  198.16.15.254
# 3 Jessie 192.168.25.200
```

but `data.table` is a bit faster...

```
library( data.table )
library( tidyverse )
setDT( IP_LIST )[str_extract( IP, "[0-9]+$" ) %>% as.numeric() >= 128, ] )

#      User             IP
# 1:   Mary   172.16.2.129
# 2:    Kim  198.16.15.254
# 3: Jessie 192.168.25.200
```

**benchmark**

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  tidyverse = IP_LIST %>% filter( str_extract( IP, "[0-9]+$" ) %>% as.numeric() >= 128 ),
  data.table = setDT( IP_LIST )[str_extract( IP, "[0-9]+$" ) %>% as.numeric() >= 128, ] )

# Unit: microseconds
#       expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  tidyverse 726.348 764.3070 827.6146 782.9855 859.3555 1427.389   100
# data.table 510.643 588.3685 673.1204 657.6590 706.4640 1826.865   100
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` with `subset` and `sub`

```
subset(IP_LIST, as.numeric(sub(".*\\.", "", IP)) > 128)
#    User             IP
#3   Mary   172.16.2.129
#4    Kim  198.16.15.254
#6 Jessie 192.168.25.200
```